# How to print more when assertion fails?

Tags: d

```
Real opIndex(size_t row, size_t col = 0) const pure nothrow {
  assert(col + row * Col < Row * Col, "index out of bounds.");
  return _data[col + row * Col];
}
```

Today this assertion failed, and I wanted to see the actual values of `row` and `col`.  Unfortunetly, `assert` isn't like `writeln` or `writefln`, so I can't do something like:

```
assert(col + row * Col < Row * Col, "index out of bounds. row: %d  col: %d", row, col);
```

I even tried this:

```
assert(col + row * Col < Row * Col, "index out of bounds" ~ to!string(row)~ " " ~ to!string(col));
```

But I can't call `to` because `opIndex` is pure.  I could temporarily remove `pure` from `opIndex`, but that triggers a long chain of undos because other pure methods are calling `opIndex`.  Not being able to call `to` also eliminates the possibility of creating my own function to pass to `assert`.

So, What else is there to try?  I just want to print such values when assertion fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the moment, if you want to convert to or from strings in a `pure` function, you're going to have to write the conversion functions yourself. Some work has gone into making functions like `std.conv.to` `pure`, but we haven't yet reached the point where they are. Too many lower level constructs still aren't `pure`, even if they theoretically could be. A lot of work is being put into making stuff `const`-correct for the next release of dmd (2.059), and some work on `pure` goes hand-in-hand with that, since certain functions in `Object` are going to have to be `pure`, `const`, `@safe`, and `nothrow`. So, there's a good chance that `std.conv.to` will be able to be `pure` for converting to and from strings with the next release. And even if it doesn't happen with the next release, it's going to happen soon, since it does need to happen (as your predicament illustrates). But until then, you're on your own.

Assuming that all of that was sorted out, then the best way to create a string for your assertion would be

```
assert(col + row * col < row * col,
       format("index out of bounds. row: %d  col: %d", row, col));
```

which will work in a impure function, but until `format` can be `pure`, it won't work in a `pure` one.

Now, you *can* put impure stuff in a `debug` block. So, if you wanted to, you could do

```
debug
{
    assert(col + row * col < row * col,
           format("index out of bounds. row: %d  col: %d", row, col));
}
```

but then you'd have to compile with `-debug` or your assertion wouldn't be run. But regardless, `debug` will allow you to put impure code in your your `pure` function for debugging purposes and will be compiled in as long as the `-debug` flag is used, so it can serve as a temporary workaround for the current deficiencies of `format` and `to`.